I need to add a dict to another dict inside a .json file
data.json:
{
    "bank": 0,
    "injury": 0,
    "inventory": [],
    "money": 110,
    "skills": {
        "Charmer": {
            "description": "Increase by using `/beg` - Increase's your chances in begging to charm the person",
            "level": 1,
            "per": 0
        },
        "Escapist": {
            "description": "Increase by using `/flood` - Increase chance of escaping robbery attempts and floods!",
            "level": 1,
            "per": 0
        },
        "Fishing": {
            "description": "Increase by using `/fish` and can increase earnings depending on you're level.",
            "level": 1,
            "per": 0
        },
        "Luck": {
            "description": "Increaseable by drinking 'Potion of Luck' or using `/coinflip (0.25% chance)` and can change the odds of any minigame in your favor.",
            "level": 1,
            "per": 0
        },
        "Master Mind": {
            "description": "Be a owner of the bot for more then 1 year - Cannot be increased by command's or editing of database.",
            "level": 10,
            "per": 100
        }
    }
}

I need to make a new skill and add it to the current set of skills
Not sure how to do it would appreciate any help!
I tried converting the dict to a list and using .append then converting it back to a dict but it didn't work

mydict["skills"]["New Skill"] = { something } What is the difficulty?

but it didn't work Show us what you tried.  Otherwise we can only guess what you did wrong.

Also showing what you do to read and write your json would help.

Isn't it straightforward? What went wrong for you? Were you able to load the data in the dictionary?

@JohnGordon Someone covered what you did in a answer, also it is straightforward I'm just new to json in python and json in general, so i don't really know too much about it

Thank's for everyones help the answer has solved my problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To create new items in a dictionary, you can do dict["[item]"] = "value", and to load a JSON file as a dictionary, you can use the json library. Therefore, you can do it as follows:
import json
with open("data.json") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
data["skills"]["NewSkill"] = {             # Replace with actual name
    description = "NewSkill's description" # Replace with actual `description`
    level = 10                             # Replace with actual `level`
    per = 0                                # Replace with actual `per`
}
with open("data.json", "w+") as data_file:
    json.dump(data, data_file)


Thank's, I'll try it in a few minutes and come back with a result

This worked quite well and opened me up to more things todo with skills!

@DisguisedTG You're welcome. Would you mind clicking on the check mark, so others know this is a working answer?

Yeah of course!
